# Cannot access Windows 10 host using RDP after uninstalling Norton

Tags: rdp, windows-10

After uninstalling Norton, I lost access to a Windows 10 host using RDP.  Currently using TeamViewer to logon. RDP displays an error:

"Your Remote Desktop Service session has ended, possibly for one of the following reasons"

[image]

I didn't change anything at all other than uninstalling Norton with NRN (Norton Removal Tool). What happened?

Comment: https://support.norton.com/sp/en/us/home/current/contact

Comment: Obviously every Windows endpoint has a builtin firewall. You need to check those settings to ensure it is configured correctly, and to confirm the endpoint is listening on port 3389.

Comment: @GregAskew Everything is fine with the ports. The problem is not the ports. When I try to connect it shows `Configuring remote session` then an error message `Your Remote Desktop Service session has ended, possibly for one of the following reasons`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Norton, then uninstalled it again. The problem persists.
What I did next:

1. Open windows local group policy editor (press “Windows” + “R” to open Run window, input “gpedit.msc” and click “Enter” to open Local Group Policy Editor)
2. **Disable** `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration >  Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services> Remote Desktop Session Host > Remote Session Environment > Use WDDM graphics display driver for Remote Desktop Connections`
3. **Enable** `Local Computer Policy > Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Remote Desktop Services>Remote Desktop Connection Client>Turn off UDP on Client > Turn off UDP on Client`
4. **Enable** `Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components > Remote Desktop Services > Remote Desktop Session Host > Connections > Allow users to connect remotely by using Remote Desktop Services`
5. Restart computer

The problem is gone. What's happened, I still don't understand. But I currently have RDP access to the server.